# fstream and ofstream operator << difference

Tags: c++

I want to overload operator<< to serialize an object to a file (append).   Which stream should I use?  `ofstream` or `fstream`?   what is the difference?

```
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& ofs, const MyData&);
std::fstream& operator<<(std::fstream& fs, const MyData&)
```

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 15):

You should overload the operator for ostream, then you can use it naturally for an instance of any class which derives from that - ofstream, fstream (inherits from iostream, which inherits from both istream and ostream), ostringstream and stringstream (inherits iostream, too)

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyData&);
```

Comment: +1 from me. I came within an ace of posting a very similar question this morning.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to overload for `std::ostream`. Why should your implementation be restricted to a special type of output stream if it can be more general? You also get the benfit of printing your serialization to `std::cout` which simplyfies debugging.

A good overview about the relations of iostreams and the usage of inheritance is given [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/). Also every overview page to a specific streams shows the inheritance relations.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `ofstream("file.txt")` is the same as `fstream("file.txt", ios::out)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to read from the same file, use `fstream`.  If append-only, use `ofstream`.  In either case, if you don't want to overwrite existing data, use the `ios::app` flag when opening.